# C - reading from file (pretty simple)

Tags: c, stdio

I have this code where I want to read from a text file each line and then print it to the standard output. For no reason it only saves the last line of the file in that array of chars.
Any tips why(some explanations are)?

```
  9 int main(){
 10     FILE * f;
 11     char buffer[255];
 12     char * arr[255];
 13     int i=0,n;
 14 
 15     f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
 16     while(1){
 17         if(fgets(buffer,255,f) != NULL ){
 18             arr[i++] = buffer;
 19         }else break;
 20     }
 21     n=i;
 22     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 23         printf("%s",arr[i]);
 24     }
 25 
 26     fclose(f);
 27     return 0;
 28 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program only has one one buffer that gets overwritten with each line of the file

EDIT:

```
char* buf;
while(1){
   buf = malloc(255);
   if(fgets(buf,255,f) != NULL ){
        arr[i++] = buf;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: arr[i] only gets a pointer to buffer.  so in the end, every entry in arr just contains the address of buffer, and buffer contains the last line of the file

Comment: You need to strcpy the contents I think to the arr[] and before that allocate memory.

Comment: then I have to save each time for each buffer read char by char?

Comment: you could allocate a new buffer for each call to fgets, then store that pointer in arr[i]

Comment: or can i set it to null on each step? (yes/no)

Comment: @nickNatra, not sure what you mean.  set what to null?

Comment: the buffer,
something like 
`arr[i++]=buffer;
buffer= null;
`

Comment: ok, i'm dumb; i guess the sollution will be to copy each char from the buffer to the array then?

Comment: @nickNatra, you don't need to copy anything.  Your issue is that you haven't allocated memory for your strings.  arr[] just holds space for pointers to strings, not the strings themselves

Answer (score 1):

`char * arr[255]` is a pointer to an array of 255 characters. When you assign `arr[i] = buffer` you are making the pointer point to `buffer` for each element of your (unallocated) array. Therefore every element will point to the same `char buffer[255]`, which will have only the last line in it by the time you get to printing.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  FILE * f;
  char buffer[255];
  char * arr[255];
  int i=0,n;

  f = fopen("c:\\temp\\input.txt", "r");
  while(1){
     if(fgets(buffer,255,f) != NULL ){
         arr[i] = (char *) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
         strcpy(arr[i++], buffer);
     }else break;
 }
 n=i;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     printf("%s",arr[i]);
 }

 fclose(f);
 for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
     free(arr[j]);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You never increment i.  In your reading loop you save to 0 then i++.  But it doesn't save the new i value into i.  So your i is 0 for your next iteration.  You need to add "i = i + 1" after "arr[i++] = buffer;"

Comment: And the i++ is not needed in the "arr[i++] = buffer;"  it should be "arr[i] = buffer;"